# Android WebView programatically turning off Predict network actions

Tags: android, ajax, google-chrome, android-webview

Our Android app uses a webview that displays a web page that utilizes some boilerplate ajax get and post requests for the user to get and manipulate data on the server. We have noticed that Chrome performs horribly on many phones with this web page, usually cheaper phones.  A simple post request will sometimes take 10 to 15 seconds to complete.  This happens both inside the webview or using Chrome stand-alone.  Firefox stand-alone on this phone works great as well.  I have another very old and slower phone that I bought internationally a couple years ago that uses the Phoenix browser (mozilla based?) which must be what it uses for its webview and it it works great.

If we disable Chrome's "Predict network actions" in Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Privacy the page behaves very well. Obviously having users do that on their own isn't a great option.

I don't know how to disable this programmatically in our Android app.  I was thinking about switching to GeckoView because Mozilla works great.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have found there is no method to do this found in the Android documentation.  Just wanted to follow up on this.